# MVC model - how to update one row in DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-update

I am new to MVC. I am adding into the database OK with this code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Add(CourseModel course)
    {
        course.UserID = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

        _db.Class.Add(course);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

But how do I correctly update a 'course' if I already have it in the DB, but the user updated one field?. 
I can delete it, and then read the updated one and that works OK but I'm pretty sure that is not the correct way of doing it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Assuming that you are using Entity Framework, [read this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160288/how-to-update-object-with-no-data-contexts

Comment: Your question seems to be not related to MVC itself; it looks more like you're asking about "How to update one row in DB in Entity Framework?" or smth like that. If that's true - can you please update your question and tags so the ones who know EF can actually find it and help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using EF, to update a record in database. Using the following code

```
_db.Entry<Course>(course).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
_db.SaveChanges();
```